# pass the variable as class name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the class name 'views-row5' in a variable 'classN'.I want to pass this to the jquery for find the class name 'views-row5' using variable 'classN' and add the class 'hello'.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var classN="views-row5"
$('.carousel-inner li').each(function()
  {$(this).find(classN).addClass('hello');});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Seriously, you forgot prefixing `.`? Closing it as TYPO

Comment: `.find("views-row5")` will look for `<views-row5>` elements.  You simply forgot the `.` at the beginning of the class selector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var classN = "views-row5"
  $('.carousel-inner li').each(function() {
    $(this).find("."+classN).addClass('hello');
  });
});
```

```css
.hello {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <li>
    <div class="views-row4">1</div>
    <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="views-row4">1</div>
    <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

1. Add `.` to find the class you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

you are forget the `.` represent the class in selector

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var classN="views-row5"
$('.carousel-inner li').each(function()
  {$(this).find('.'+classN).addClass('hello');});
 });
```

```css
.hello{
color:green;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the variable assignment, you have to add the dot for the class. like `var classN=".views-row5"`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var classN=".views-row5"
$('.carousel-inner li').each(function()
  {$(this).find(classN).addClass('hello');});
 });
```

```css
.hello {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div class="views-row4">1</div>
     <div class="views-row5">2</div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var classN="views-row5"
   $('.' + classN).addClass('hello');
});
```